# CSS "word" selector?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to select and style a specific word via css?
Example case:

```
<div>Roses are red violets are blue. This is red that is blue.</div>
```

and a certain type of styling would make all `red` words in that sentence, red; and all `blue` words in that sentence blue.

EDIT:
I've found this page, that works somehow. Not sure how it works (vertain elements are colored -- how?)
http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: I don't think so. CSS about html elements, the words are textNode. But I am not sure. Only the search through the javascript

Comment: Sorry, nothing comes to mind. CSS applies selectors to *elements*, not to individual text nodes. You could do this with some nifty JavaScript though.

Comment: @danko I already did, this is why you see the question here.

Comment: @Katana314: how is scanning the whole page for words nifty? Adding `<span>`s to the HTML and then applying the CSS is the only sane thing to do - if possible, of course.

Comment: @DanMan That's a good question. You should ask it to the person who suggested scanning the whole page for words.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible. You have to use javascript for this.

Comment: this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible using only CSS. You can use Javascript or jQuery to achieve what you want though :

- You search the content of your `div`to try and find the words like "red", "blue"
- You wrap a `span`with a `class="color"`around the word
- You apply the styling to that span in your CSS

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't believe that is possible. You'd have do add in some CSS like this:

```
<div>
    Roses are 
    <span style="color:#f33">red</span>
    violets are 
    <span style="color:#36f">blue</span>.
    This is 
    <span style="color:#f33">red</span>
    that is
    <span style="color:#36f">blue</span>.
</div>
```

Or you could create a class for each colour, like this (in the to the head section in your HTML file, or put it in a separate file if you want to use it on multiple pages)

```
<style>.red { color:#f33; } .blue { color:#36f; }</style>
```

And then use this code:

```
<div>
    Roses are
    <span class="red">red</span>
    violets are
    <span class="blue">blue</span>.
    This is 
    <span class="red">red</span>
    that is 
    <span class="blue">blue</span>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a span around the word red with class="redword" and target that with css

```
 <span class="redword">red</span>
 <span class="blueword">blue</span>
 .redword{color:red;}.blueword{color:blue;}
```