# How to highlight one specific word in text using only css?

Tags: css

How to highlight one specific word in text using only css? I can`t add another tag inside tag p.

```
<p class="header_heading">
      Some text that I need to highlight
</p>
```

Comment: You can't acces to a string in a tag just with css. You can just acces to the first letter or maybe the first line of a paragraph.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS "word" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910738/css-word-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you cannot do that unless you add some java script and parse text / add style for a single word.

Theoretically you can research for CSS pseudo element such as specific word or similar, but I do not remember anything that exists and can help unless you parse the content.